# How do you find a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ such that it contains specific elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

How do you find a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ such that it contains specific elements:
$(2,4,-1,0), (-4,-8,2,1)$

Comment: Pick any two additional vectors you want, then just verify that these two new ones, with the two old ones, form an independent set.  The probability is very high that this will work, for just about any random way you are picking these two new vectors.

Comment: so ill put them in reduced row echelon form then pick independent vectors to those rows?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to pick the two new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want: $$\det\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & a_1 & b_1 \\ 4 & -8 & a_2 & b_2 \\ -1 & 2 & a_3 & b_3 \\ 0 & 1 & a_4 & b_4 \end{bmatrix}\neq 0$$

Pick any eight numbers that work.